# What's the difference between these 2 comparisons?

Tags: javascript, function

What's the difference between this...

```
(function () {})() === (function () {})()
// => true
```

and this...

```
(function () {}) === (function () {})
// => false
```

The prior comparison evaluates to `true`, yet the latter evaluates to `false`. Why is that?

Comment: First one is comparing the result of **invoking** function, the second is just comparing the functions

Comment: the first one compares `undefined === undefined` as you are invoking 2 functions which don't have a return statement

Comment: I see. And since in the first comparison both functions return `undefined`, the comparison check is the same as `undefined === undefined`.

Comment: The second one is comparing 2 different functions which will not be equal

Comment: Would it be more obvious if you did: `function foo() {}; function bar() {}; console.log(foo() === bar()); console.log(foo === bar);` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(function () {})()
```

is an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). This means, it is a function that gets immediately executed and the actual value of it is its `return` value. This function doesn’t have a `return` statement, therefore the value is `undefined`. `undefined === undefined` is `true`.

```
(function () {})
```

however, is a function. A function is not a primitive value, but like an object. In JavaScript, when comparing objects (or functions), the *references* are compared. Because both `(function () {})`s create a *new* function, these aren’t the *same* function, hence the comparison yields `false`.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case,

```
(function () {})() === (function () {})()
```

you create *two different, but similar function objects*; execute them and then compare their results. Since both the functions don't return anything explicitly, JavaScript will return `undefined` by default. So, that effectively becomes

```
undefined === undefined
```

---

In the second case,

```
(function () {}) === (function () {})
```

you create *two different*, but similar function objects and compare them. The `===` operator will return true, only if both the function objects are the same. Since they are different in this case, it returns `false`. The only way to get this comparison to return true would be to compare the same function, like this

```
var func = (function () {});
console.log(func === func);
// true
```